# Data.Table rolling join by group

Tags: r, join, data.table

How can I find the **last** value, **prior to test.day**, for each (`loc.x`, `loc.y`) pair?

```
dt <- data.table( 
  loc.x = as.integer(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1)),
  loc.y = as.integer(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)),
  time = as.IDate(c("2015-03-11", "2015-05-10", "2015-09-27",
                    "2015-11-25", "2014-09-13", "2015-08-19")), 
  value = letters[1:6]
)

setkey(dt, loc.x, loc.y, time)
test.day <- as.IDate("2015-10-01")
```

Required output:

```
   loc.x loc.y value
1:     1     1     a
2:     1     2     f
3:     3     1     c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to use the `last` function:

```
dt[, last(value[time < test.day]), by = .(loc.x, loc.y)]
```

which gives:

```
   loc.x loc.y V1
1:     1     1  a
2:     1     2  f
3:     3     1  c
```

Comment: I think `dt[time < test.day, last(value), by = .(loc.x, loc.y)]` will be much more efficient as it won't recalculate `time < test.day` by group, but this seems almost identical to the other answer to me at least.

Answer (score 6):

You can first subset the rows where `time < test.day` (which should be quite efficient because it is not done by group) and then select the last `value` per group. To do that you can either use `tail(value, 1L)` or, as suggested by Floo0, `value[.N]`, resulting in:

```
dt[time < test.day, tail(value, 1L), by = .(loc.x, loc.y)]
#   loc.x loc.y V1
#1:     1     1  a
#2:     1     2  f
#3:     3     1  c
```

or

```
dt[time < test.day, value[.N], by = .(loc.x, loc.y)]
```

Note that this works because the data is sorted due to `setkey(dt, loc.x, loc.y, time)`.

Comment: Of you could use `value[.N]` instead if `tail(value, 1L)`.

Comment: @Floo0, sure, that's another option.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using a rolling join after creating a lookup table

```
indx <- data.table(unique(dt[ ,.(loc.x, loc.y)]), time = test.day)  
dt[indx, roll = TRUE, on = names(indx)]
#    loc.x loc.y       time value
# 1:     1     1 2015-10-01     a
# 2:     1     2 2015-10-01     f
# 3:     3     1 2015-10-01     c
```

---

Or a very similar option suggested by @eddi

```
dt[dt[, .(time = test.day), by = .(loc.x, loc.y)], roll = T, on = c('loc.x', 'loc.y', 'time')]
```

---

Or a one liner which will be less efficient as it will call `[.data.table` by group

```
dt[, 
    .SD[data.table(test.day), value, roll = TRUE, on = c(time = "test.day")], 
    by = .(loc.x, loc.y)
  ]
#    loc.x loc.y V1
# 1:     1     1  a
# 2:     1     2  f
# 3:     3     1  c
```

Comment: Hmm, how about `dt[dt[, .(time = test.day), by = .(loc.x, loc.y)], roll = T, on = c('loc.x', 'loc.y', 'time')]` instead, to avoid the `[.data.table` in a loop?

Comment: Yeah, my thought was `indx <- data.table(unique(dt[ ,.(loc.x, loc.y)]), time = test.day) ; dt[indx, roll = TRUE, on = names(indx)]` actually, but this all seems like an over kill and I was about to delete this.

Comment: @eddi I added both into the answer. I guess this will now be more competitive.